# My first 3D printing - I need some advice or tips

Tags: support-structures

It is my first time for 3D printing, I read some tips for forms, minimal thickness, angles, round or flat, but I am still not sure if I am going to do all well for the first time.

For my college final project, I had to make a small prototype and it requires an enclosure.

My concerns are:

- I am not sure if my design will require supports
- Overhangs
- Printing Orientation

Here part of my design:

- Most walls are 2 mm+ thick
- The lid is a separate file, but it is really simple just a flat rectangle, I believe it is going well the first time

[image: Screenshot of 3D model]

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: Is this hollow? You would need support to hold up the top middle bit. You may get away with no supports if you flip the model upside down.

Comment: So run it through a slicer and see if supports are generated

Comment: yes, it is hollow inside. @CarlWitthoft I am designing with AutoCad not sure if it has that tool btw I have 3 days using it I am pretty noob :)

Comment: Are you asking for slicing recommendations?

Comment: Export from AutoCad in STL format, try Slic3r with some settings (or use Prusa Slicer that has many profiles already there) and then come back here with more specific questions. Right now it's too broad.

Comment: Why are these concerns? The slicer will take care of putting in supports when instructed. It shouldn't matter if support is used unless you want a near perfect smooth inner side. Which side needs to the most aesthetic side?

Comment: The lid will probably print better upside down.

Comment: What do you need that huge rectangular slab for?
If you replaced your fillets with chamfers, this would print perfectly fine "upside down" without that slab, which you could print seperately.
You shouldn't require supports for things you've designed yourself in 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

I see this:

> I had to make a small prototype and it requires an enclosure

and this:

> yes, it is hollow inside

How do you intend to get your item inside the result? This part really needs to be *two pieces* with *two separate prints*. Basically, a box and the lid, where you leave space for screws, include tabs, or plan for glue connections.

Finish that alteration, and the support issue suddenly becomes **much** easier. Most slicers have options to generate support for you, including limiting support to spaces between the model and build plate. Now you can rotate the angle at the which the part is printed in order to minimize your support needs, or so that most of the connection points for the support will not be visible in the finished product.

Comment: Hi Joel, I have an second file which I use for the lid, just a flat surface, I believe it is not a big deal and I am going to glue that into this one.

Comment: What Slicer would you recommend to me?, the Slicers have a function for auto supports if it is required?

Comment: @Kirito-kun Slic3r and Ultimaker Cura are popular and free slicers, both have options for adding support structures.